# Application event logging for statistics

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, logging, datastore

I have app in production and working. It is hosted on heroku and uses Postgres 9.3 in the cloud. There are 2 databases: master and (read-only follower) slave. There are tables like `Users`, `Likes`, `Followings`, `Subscriptions` and so on. We need to store complete log about events like `userCreated`, `userDeleted`, `userLikedSomething`, `userUnlikedSomething`, `userFollowedSomeone`, `userUnfollowedSomeone` and so on. Later on we have to prepare statistic reports/charts about current and historical data. The main proble is that when user is deleted it is just removed from db so we can't retrieve users that were deleted from db because they are not stored in db anymore. Same applies to likes/unlikes follows/unfollows and so on. There are few things I don't know how to handle properly:

1. If we will store events in same database with foreign keys to user profiles then historical data will change because each event will be "linked" to current user profile which will change in time.
2. If we will store events in separate postgres database (db just for logs to offload the main database) then to join the events with actual user profiles we would have to use cross-db joins (`dblink`) which might be slow I guess (I have never used this feature before). Anyway this wont solve the problem from point 1.
3. I thought about using different type of database for storing logs - maybe MongoDb - as I remember mongoDb is more "write-heavy" than postgres (which is more "read-heavy"?) so it might be more suitable for storing logs/events. However then I would have to store user profiles in two databases (and even user profile per each event to solve point 1).

I know this is very general question but maybe there is some kind of standard approach or special database type for storing such data?

Comment: If you have many thousands of users, their data changes frequently, and you need to do serious analysis around the users and their actions, you could start thinking about a separate reporting system (data warehouse?) which will be fed from the live database. Reading this blog should give you some idea http://www.kimballgroup.com/1998/05/surrogate-keys/. Also google slowly changing dimensions.

Comment: Yes we have now ~60k users and many visits per month so data will grow quite quickly I guess.

Comment: Ok so now I know we need data warehouse for our app. Is there something as DWaaS? We have our production database and we have to store specific informations from that table (for example row created/deleted in certain table and so on along with storing some additional data from other tables (state?)). I am looking for simplest solution - well, simplest to integrate, but flexible.

Comment: This might be useful to you: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

Comment: There are DWaaS, they provide the technology stack. Here is one - http://www.talend.com/blog/2013/10/26/teradata-dwaas-uses-talend. No idea how good they are, or if you need something like that. We use clicky for traffic analysis. We use PostgreSQL fdw to read from app/web logs and also move user data from live system (PostgreSQL tables) using PostgreSQL fdw. The consolidation is done in a daily batch.

Comment: Hmm is there any service/solution just to save DAILY SNAPSHOT of whole database in DataWarehouse and the to be able to use time dimension somehow when querying for statistics?